# Strange behaviour of JavaScript getElementById

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
    var greet;
    var now = new Date();
    var curHours = now.getHours();
    if (curHours >=4 && curHours <12) {
    greet = "Good morning, ";
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    }
    else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18) {
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    greet = "Good day, ";
    }
    else if (curHours >=18 && curHours <24) {
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    greet = "Good evening, ";
    }
    else if (curHours >=24 && curHours <4) {
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    greet = "Good night, ";
    }
    else {
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    greet = "Hey, ";
    }
    document.write (greet);
```

document.write works ok, but in span when the second condition start to work 
`else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18)` I get **undefined in span**.

```
<span id="greetTxt"></span>
```

Why so? First condition works ok. Local time when bug happend was 13:30.

Comment: There is nothing "strange" here. If you get 'undefined' showing as the text/content set, what does that say about the value *actually* assigned as the content? Trace it back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

instead of

```
else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18) {
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    greet = "Good day, ";
}
```

use

```
else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18) {
    greet = "Good day, ";
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;

}
```

Because greet has no value assigned to it . So for every condition assign greet frist and then put it in the inner html

Answer (score 1):

You are defining value before defining variable greet thus you are getting `undefined`.

So, first define the value and then assign it in innerHTML like:

```
   var greet;
    var now = new Date();
    var curHours = now.getHours();
    if (curHours >=4 && curHours <12) {
    greet = "Good morning, ";
    document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
    }
     else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18) {
        greet = "Good day, ";
        document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;

        }
        else if (curHours >=18 && curHours <24) {
        greet = "Good evening, ";
        document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;

        }
        else if (curHours >=24 && curHours <4) {
        greet = "Good night, ";
        document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;

        }
        else {
        greet = "Hey, ";
        document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks, had to give "Accept answer" for the first right one.

Comment: sure, I was late as I copied and modified your all else if text.

Answer (score 1):

Writing repeated code is not a good practice. Assign `greet` variable based on the condition and put it in the `.innerHTML`.

Try this:

```
var greet;
var now = new Date();
var curHours = now.getHours();
if (curHours >=4 && curHours <12) {
    greet = "Good morning, ";
}
else if (curHours >=12 && curHours <18) {
    greet = "Good day, ";
}
else if (curHours >=18 && curHours <24) {
    greet = "Good evening, ";
}
else if (curHours >=24 && curHours <4) {
    greet = "Good night, ";
}
else {
    greet = "Hey, ";
}
document.getElementById("greetTxt").innerHTML = greet; 
document.write (greet);
```

Comment: Thanks, had to give "Accept answer" for the first right one.

Comment: @Cove no issues. glad to help you.!